# Data value on a given date

Tags: sql, postgresql, metabase

This time I have a table on a PostgreSQL database that contains the employee name, the date that he started working and the date that he leaves the company, in the cases of the employee still remains in the company, this field has null value.
Knowing this, I would like to know how many people was working on a predetermined date, ex:

I would like to know how many people works on the company in January 2021.

I don't know where to start, in some attempts I got the number of hires and layoffs per month, but I need to show this accumulated value per month, in another column.

I hope I made myself understood, I'll leave the last SQL I got here.

```
select reference, sum(hires) from
(
select 
    date_trunc('month', date_hires) as reference,
    count(*) as hires   
from
    ponto_mais_relatorio_colaboradores
group by 
    date_hires
union all

select  
    date_trunc('month', date_layoff) as reference,
    count(*)*-1 as layoffs
from 
    ponto_mais_relatorio_colaboradores
group by 
    date_layoff    
) as reference

join calendar_aux on calendar_aux.ano_mes = reference

group by reference
order by reference
```

Answer (score 0):

Break the requirement down. The question: how many are employed on any given date? That would include all hired before that date and do not have a layoff date plus all hired before with a layoff date later then the date your interested period. I.e you are interested in Jan so you still want to count an employee with a layoff date in Feb. With that in place convert into SQL. The preceding is available from select comparing dates. other issue is that Jan is not a date, it is a range of dates, so you need each date. You can use generate series to create each day in Jan. Then Join the generated dates with and selection from your table. Resulting query:

```
with jan_dates( jdate ) as  
     ( select generate_series( date '2021-01-01' 
                             , date '2021-01-31'
                             , interval '1' day 
                             )::date
     )
 select jdate "Date", count(*) "Employees"
   from jan_dates j 
   join employees e 
     on (    e.date_hires <= j.jdate
         and (   e.date_layoff is null
              or e.date_layoff > j.jdate
             )
        )
 group by j.jdate
 order by j.jdate;
```

**Note:** Not tested.